# How to set cell background color in excel using java + poi

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi

So far I did bellow coding using Spring MVC.

Important- I am not using here `HSSFWorkbook`

**So what is the equivalent of the POI method setCellStyle in StreamingReader**

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("file path"));
    StreamingReader  reader = StreamingReader.builder()
            .rowCacheSize(90000000)   
            .bufferSize(4096)  
            .sheetIndex(0)
            .read(is);            
    for (Row r : reader) {
       Test_huge_excel_data data = new Test_huge_excel_data();
       data.setCol1(r.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
       data.setCol2(r.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

       drtamminaService.saveExcelData(data);
    }
```

My requirement is suppose if a cell data is not formatted well example "wrong data format" so I want to change that particular cell background color.

But if I am using this am able to do it

```
XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fileInputStream);
XSSFCellStyle style = myWorkBook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
row.getCell(30).setCellStyle(style);
```

But when I am using this code I am not able to load a huge amount of file.

In my above code only I need changes to add style.

Comment: Did you get any error? on doing above

Comment: How big is the file that you want to process?

Comment: @RajuSharma No i did't get any error .. i din't know how I have to apply cell background color on above code..

Comment: @JensS File is having 130 column and 36000 rows

Comment: @RajuSharma In above code I am not able to get `workbook`, if I will get workbook then it could be possible.

Comment: What do you mean: not getting the workbook? You are initializing it, aren't you? Do you mean the sheet?

Comment: @JensS U can see instead of using `XSSFWorkbook ` here I am using `StreamingReader`

Comment: OK, now I get the question: you would like to have the equivalent of the POI method setCellStyle in StreamingReader, right?

Comment: @JensS Yes exactly ..

Comment: @Mickey Patel: The [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) is named **Reader**. There is a [StreamingWorkbook](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingWorkbook.java) which implements `Workbook` but most of it's methods are  not implemented yet. So it is a draft until now. But it's source is open. So feel free to get it ready. But the more of the methods you will implement the more it will be like `apache poi` also in how much resources needed.

Comment: @AxelRichter Is it not possible to read huge amount of data in `HSSFWorkbook` instead of `StreamingReader`.

Comment: @Mickey Patel: You mean **creating** a `HSSFWorkbook` by reading from a huge `*.xls` file? With this you will have the same problems as with **creating** a `XSSFWorkbook` by reading from a huge `*.xlsx` file. You will need as much RAM memory as the file content needs since it is not possible creating only parts of a workbook. It is only possible to read the data from the `*.xls` or `*.xlsx` files in event driven manner **instead** creating the fully accessible `Workbook` object. This is mentioned in [The New Halloween Document](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution that might help you:

1. I have set rowCacheSize to 1000 (with your higher value, it took way too long)
2. I have created the cellStyle myself and used setCellStyle on it.

I have - however - not been able to find a save method so far, so I could not test it.

```
    StreamingReader reader = StreamingReader
            .builder()
            .rowCacheSize(1000)
            .bufferSize(4096)
            .sheetIndex(0)
            .read(is);

    XSSFCellStyle style = new XSSFCellStyle(new StylesTable());
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);


    for (Row row : reader) {
        System.out.println(row.getRowNum());
        row.getCell(3).setCellStyle(style);
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help .. but while doing this I am getting `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`

Comment: Does it start to count the rows, or is the stream closed from the beginning?

Comment: At `r.getCell(128).setCellStyle(style);` place i am getting `com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.NotSupportedException`

Comment: I don't get that error, but it seems that the StreamingReader does not support writing to files so far anyway, so it might not be possible to do the job with this library (not sure about this, though).

Answer (score 0):

The [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) is named **Reader** because it is for reading only. There is a [StreamingWorkbook](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingWorkbook.java) which implements Workbook but most of it's methods are not implemented yet. So it is a draft until now.

If it comes to huge `Excel` files then we must consider a totally different approach than creating `HSSFWorkbook` or `XSSFWorkbook` from those huge files.

A `Workbook` can only be created as a whole. But of  course we could take single parts of the `Excel` files like the sheets part (containing rows and cells) or the styles part (containing the styles of the cells, the fonts, fills, borders etc.) or the shared strings part (containing text contents of the cells) and parse those. This leads to less resource consuming since the single parts are less huge than the whole file. But it also needs more knowledge about the internal structure of the file. And the easiest task is reading and parsing the single parts but if it comes to changings and so to the need writing those into the part streams, then it gets quickly complicated because then we need also to know about and to take into account the part relationships.

Fortunately the `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`) parts are `XML` and as such to parse (read) and also to write using [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html).

The following code uses this approach. It gets the styles table part and the sheet1 part form the ZIP package of an `*.xlsx` file and then sets red background color in each cell of every 5th row from Sheet1 of this file. Also if the file maybe huge, the code should nevertheless running with as less possible resource amount.

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

class StaxReadAndWriteTestRowBGColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   File file = new File("file.xlsx");
   OPCPackage opcpackage = OPCPackage.open(file);

   //get the styles table
   PackagePart stylestabletablepart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/styles.xml")).get(0);
   StylesTable stylestable = new StylesTable(stylestabletablepart);

   //get the sheet1 package part
   PackagePart sheetpart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml")).get(0);

   //create reader and writer for the sheet1 package part            
   XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(sheetpart.getInputStream());
   XMLEventWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(sheetpart.getOutputStream());

   //create a factory for producing XML elements and attributes
   XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();

   int rowsCount = 0;

   Map<Integer, Integer> styleIdxMap = new HashMap<>(); //a Map for mapping old styleIdx to new styleIdx

   while(reader.hasNext()){ //loop over all XML in sheet1.xml
    XMLEvent event = (XMLEvent)reader.next();

    if(event.isStartElement()){
     StartElement startElement = (StartElement)event;
     QName startElementName = startElement.getName();
     if(startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) { //start element of row
      rowsCount++;
     } else if (startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("c")) { //start element of cell
      if (rowsCount % 5 == 0) { // every 5th row
       Attribute attribute;

       Iterator attributeIterator = startElement.getAttributes(); //get cell's attributes
       List<Attribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<>();
       int styleIdx = 0;
       while (attributeIterator.hasNext()) {
        attribute = (Attribute)attributeIterator.next();
        if ("s".equals(attribute.getName().getLocalPart())) { //cell has style attribute already
         styleIdx = Integer.valueOf(attribute.getValue()); //so get the styleIdx 
                                                           //but don't put in the attributeList since we wants creating it new
        } else {
         attributeList.add(attribute);
        }
       }

       XSSFCellStyle cellstyle;
       cellstyle = stylestable.getStyleAt(styleIdx);

       if (cellstyle.getFillForegroundColor() != IndexedColors.RED.getIndex() 
           && cellstyle.getFillPatternEnum() != FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGR‌​OUND) {
        if (styleIdxMap.get(styleIdx) == null) { //old cell style is not mapped until now
         cellstyle = (XSSFCellStyle)cellstyle.clone(); //so clone style
         styleIdxMap.put(styleIdx, (int)cellstyle.getIndex()); //and put in the map
        } else {
         cellstyle = stylestable.getStyleAt(styleIdxMap.get(styleIdx)); //else get from already mapped style
        }
        cellstyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
        cellstyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGR‌​OUND);
       }

       styleIdx = (int)cellstyle.getIndex(); //get final styleIdx
       attribute = eventFactory.createAttribute("s", Integer.toString(styleIdx)); //create new style attribute
       attributeList.add(attribute); //add it to the attributeList now
       StartElement newstartElement = eventFactory.createStartElement(startElementName, 
                                                                      attributeList.iterator(), 
                                                                      startElement.getNamespaces());

       event = newstartElement; //create a new event for the writer using the new cell StartElement
      }
     }
    }
    writer.add(event); //by default write each read event
   }
   writer.flush();

   //write out the styles table
   OutputStream out = stylestabletablepart.getOutputStream();
   stylestable.writeTo(out);
   out.close();

   opcpackage.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```