# Updating existing Excel file in Java Apache POI without using InputStream

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to update an existing Excel file (xlsx).

Constructors like `XSSFWorkbook(java.io.File file)` and `XSSFWorkbook(OPCPackage pkg)` open the file in a read only mode and don't allow modifications. So I have to use `XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream is)` and the memory footprint (JVM memory and Java Heap) is too high. I can't use VM args to set max memory size, as I have to respect the memory requirements of other programs running in parallel.

Using `SXSSFWorkbook` was another solution but it is essentially a wrapper around `XSSFWorkbook`. Same problems persist that were with `XSSFWorkbook`.

I went to other posts at SO and couldn't find any relevant answer. Can anybody help me with this please? I am fine with storing temporary files.

Comment: I had good results (lower memory usage) using new SXSSFWorkbook(-1) along with SXSSFSheet.flushRows() but that was for creating a new file, not updating one. I think you should try SXSSFWorkbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear. In reality it is not "How to open `XSSFWorkbook` without using `InputStream`?" but "How to reduce the memory footprint of `XSSFWorkbook`? ". And the answer to this question is: It can't be reduced, such as `apache poi` is programmed now. Else the `apache poi` developers would must be as stupid that they had programmed `apache poi` especially to waste memory. They have not.

But there are too much abstraction levels used.

All is based on XML. But users of programming libraries do not want bothering with XML and at least not with that kind of XML which is split into multiple files in a ZIP archive which are linked together using special relation XML files. So on top of the XML there is `ooxml-schemas`, a library which gets the XML of the single files into usable `java` objects. And there is `org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*` to manage the relations.

To get all benefit of this, all the usable `java` objects (workbook, sheets, rows, cells, drawings, tables, pivot-tables, charts, ...) and the relations of those **must** be in memory to be ready to use. Or temporary files would must be used to store them temporary after got them out of the `*.xlsx` ZIP archive. Working directly in the ZIP file system is not an option in my opinion because of the behavior of changes in such type of filesystem.

But using temporary files is not provided by `apache poi`. Only `SXSSF` uses temporary files for worksheets, but only for writing new `*.xlsx` files, not for reading and updating such files.

Additional, to be compatible with the binary `BIFF` `*.xls` file format as most as possible, there is another level added. This is the `SS` and `XSSF` level which provides the high level classes of `apache poi`. And because of that there are now additional `java` objects for workbook, sheets, rows, cells, drawings, tables, pivot-tables, charts, .. additional to the low level `ooxml-schemas` classes in memory.

So ... memory full when it comes to big `*.xlsx` files. ;-)

Solutions?

To be as memory friendly as possible, unzip the `*.xlsx` ZIP archive and do working directly with the XML in it. Of course this is very laborious, especially for creating new contents and when it comes to  taking the relations into account. I have shown simple examples for this in my answers here. For example: [How to modify a large Excel file when memory is an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739290/how-to-modify-a-large-excel-file-when-memory-is-an-issue/56757630#56757630) and [How to set cell background color in excel using java + poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197278/how-to-set-cell-background-color-in-excel-using-java-poi/46217693#46217693).

Or do programming an extension for `apache poi` which uses temporary files instead of holding all in memory. Of course this also is laborious and has disadvantages for systems which do not provide using temporary files.